# How do you display express validator error in react frontend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, mern, express-validator

I'm trying to get the error thrown by express-validator to render on the frontend for the user. The error will log out in the terminal, but I can't figure out how to send that data to the frontend and actually render it for the user to see.

This application is a MERN stack with Redux using JavaScipt on the frontend.

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')

// load Model
const Model = require('../models/Model')

// @Route   POST api/create
// @Desc    Create
// @Action  create()
// @Access  Private
router.post(
  '/create',
  [
    //account details validation
    check('firstName', 'Enter a First Name').not().isEmpty(),
    check('lastName', 'Enter a Last name').not().isEmpty()
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
    } = req.body

    const newEntry = {
      contactInfo: {
        name: {
          first: firstName,
          last: lastName,
        }
      }
    }

    try {
      const errors = validationResult(req)
      //Check if there are errors
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        console.log(errors)
        //If so Send response status with the error message
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ success: false, data: errors.array()[0].msg })
      } else {
        res.send(errors.array()[0].msg)
      }

      let inbox = new Model(newEntry)
      await entry.save()
      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Entry submitted successfully',
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message)
      res.status(500).json({ status: false, error: error.message })
    }
  },
)
```

terminal log:

```
Result {
[0]   formatter: [Function: formatter],
[0]   errors: [
[0]     {
[0]       value: undefined,
[0]       msg: 'Enter a First Name',
[0]       param: 'firstName',
[0]       location: 'body'
[0]     },
[0]     {
[0]       value: undefined,
[0]       msg: 'Enter a Last name',
[0]       param: 'lastName',
[0]       location: 'body'
[0]     },
[0]   ]
[0] }
```

Dependencies:

- "axios": "^0.24.0",
- "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
- "cors": "^2.8.5",
- "express": "^4.17.2",
- "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
- "jquery": "^3.6.0",
- "mongodb": "^4.2.2",
- "mongoose": "^6.1.5",
- "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
- "react": ">=17.0.2",
- "react-dom": ">=17.0.2",
- "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
- "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
- "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
- "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
- "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
- "sass": "^1.47.0",
- "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"

---

### Please post the frontend code that requests the /create route and tries to display the result –
Chris G

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { create } from '../../actions'

const Contact = ({ createInbox }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    contactInfo: {
      name: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
      }
  })

  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
  } = formData

  // Captures changes made to the form data
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    // reset alert
  }

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    create(formData)

    // Reset fromData
    setFormData({
      contactInfo: {
        name: {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
        },
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="contact mt-5">
      <div className="container">
        <form className="px-5" onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
          <div className="row mb-3">
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <label htmlFor="inputFirstName" className="form-label">
                First Name
                <sup>
                  {' '}
                  <i className="bi bi-asterisk text-warning " />
                </sup>
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="firstName"
                value={firstName}
                onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                className="form-control"
                id="inputFirstName"
                placeholder="Jane"
                aria-describedby="firstNameHelp"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <label htmlFor="inputLastName" className="form-label">
                Last Name
                <sup>
                  {' '}
                  <i className="bi bi-asterisk text-warning " />
                </sup>
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="lastName"
                value={lastName}
                onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                className="form-control"
                id="inputLastName"
                placeholder="Doe"
                aria-label="lastNameHelp"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row mb-3 mt-5 pt-5 border-top">
            <button
              type="submit"
              id="submitButton"
              className="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm col-md-1"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ Reducer: state.Reducer })

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { create })(Contact)
```

```
// @Route   POST api/create
// @Desc    Create
// @Action  create()
// @Access  Private
export const create = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }
    await axios
      .post('/api/create', formData, config)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
    dispatch({
      type: REDUX_SUCCESS,
      payload: { msg: formData, status: 'success' },
    })
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response.data.errors) {
      dispatch({
        payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
      })
    }

    dispatch({
      type: REDUX_FAIL,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the frontend code that requests the `/create` route and tries to display the result

Comment: Added the route/action/frontend - Everything works fine but getting the  `const errors = validationResult(req)` back to the front end to render the content for the user instead of logging it out in the terminal.

Comment: The 2nd dispatch call doesn't have a `type`. Also, please use `console.log(...)` at various places to see where the information ends up and how far it gets. `console.log(err)` for instance would be a good place to start.